# .htaccess URL routing

Tags: .htaccess

My codebase is located in url.com/ with /public housing index.php and .htaccess, which the servers configured to point at for url.com

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ServerSignature On
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php

RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+).([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&return=$3
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+).([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=index&return=$3
```

What I would like is the following URLS to get the following:

url.com/users/list.json `equal = module = users, action = list, return = json`

url.com/users/list.json?from=0&to=15 `equal =  module = users, action = list, return = json, from = 0, to = 15`

Is this possible? I've been banging my head against a wall for a long time trying to get this work so I'm putting a bounty on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
RewriteRule ([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)\.(json|xml)$ /testrewrite.php?module=$1&return=$3&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The QSA option will keep the query strings in tact.

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` pattern simply does not match the requested URL path as the pattern for the third path segment `[0-9]+` does not match `List`.

Comment: Well spotted.

I'm doing: RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2

but when I print_r($_GET) its empty, any idea why this could be?

Comment: @azz0r: Is there a file called “User”, “User/List”, or something similar to that? I that case this behavior can be caused by *MultiViews*.

Comment: Via /public/index.php it uses get _GET['module'] and action to load the right file and output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's `%{QUERY_STRING}` will maintain the GET variables in your rules. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+).([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&return=$3?%{QUERY_STRING}
```